# Handling errors in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How I can read error message and HTTP error status in `catch` callbcak?

Error handling in `Ember Data: 2.16.2` a little bit confusing.

Problem appear when `query` return `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` with data `{error: "Not authorized"}`. `err` does't contain error and http code (in my case `err` == `true`)

```
this.store.query('user', {
            someParam: val
          }).then((model) => {
            ....
          }).catch((err) => {
             console.log(err)
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check your API response using browser's dev tools to be sure it's correct.

Second, check your then callback - are you sure it doesn't throw `true`?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues a while back. My solution was to override the `extractErrors` function of `DS.JSONSerializer`. Then you can check the payload parameter and return errors on the form you want. Just make sure you return the errors on a form similar to the default one if you have eg. validation which depends on the api response.

See https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.JSONSerializer/methods/extractErrors?anchor=extractErrors